# Light sleep for Win 8 Laptops

Tags: windows-8, sleep, shutdown, hybrid-sleep

Is there some program allowing custom Sleeping configuration in Windows 8 on laptop?

I would like to set up these options:

- turning off CPU
- turning off Fan
- turning off HDD
- turning off screen
- keeping Power on
- keeping RAM on
- waking up on keypress/mouseclick without inserting password (keep being logged on)

(This way would be my laptop totally quiet, consuming just a little energy and very quickly put into a such "light sleep" or being ready again)

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option for you would be to put your laptop to sleep. It will only consume enemrgy(battery) to keep the RAM on. To keep the computer from asking you to enter your password on wakeup (keyboard/mouseclick), [Follow this simple tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7771/prevent-windows-asking-for-a-password-on-wake-up-from-sleepstandby/).

Comment: Thanks Tech1337. That is good enough for me :) I didn't know about this not-recquiring-password setting. Thanks a lot, best regards from Czech rep.